# Code doesn`t work as it supposed in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

While using visual studio 2019 i got problem: code doesnt work as it must work, example of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <future>

class MyClass {
public:
    void SetFx(std::function <void()> func) { fx = func; }
    void do_work()
    {
             ft = std::async([this] {
            while (true)
            {
                if (fx != NULL)
                    fx();
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "NULL\n";
                }
            }
             });
       
    }
private:
    std::future <void> ft;
    std::function <void()> fx;
};
int main()
{
    int c = 10;
    MyClass a;
    MyClass b;
    a.SetFx([&]() {std::cout << "a " << std::endl; });
    b.SetFx([&]() {std::cout << "b " << std::endl; });
    a.do_work();
    b.do_work();
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

All online compilers and project compiled without visual studio works fine. I have tried to use clang and visual2019 compilers inside visual studio, and got incorrect output.

Possible output from vs studio:

```
aNULL
NULL
a
```

Possible output not from vs studio:

```
a
b
b
a
```

Where is problem?
All compiller settings are default, optimization disabled.

Comment: Excuse me, the `while()` loop in your program seems infinite.

Comment: does the program return when you get the weird behaviour on visual studio?

Comment: @PalLaden it is, but does it matter in this example?

Comment: @jbztt did you mean exit code? it is 0

Comment: the `do_work` isn't doing what you think it's doing. the way you're using `std::async` here means that it's going to be run in deferred or async mode. also you're not calling `wait` on either of those `std::future`s. what I am basically saying is this is undefined behaviour